# How to format phone number with phone code

Tags: java, android, formatting

There is this library:

**android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils**

(or original **com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil**)

Let the phone number be **666666666**
I need to format phone number depending on phone code, so:

If I choose phoneCode "**+48**" (e.g. Poland):
I expect: phone number: **666 666 666**:

If I choose phoneCode "**+1**" (e.g. Canada)
I expect: **(666) 666-666**

So far I know I can use:
PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher
but one of it's constructor:

```
PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(String countryCode)
```

expects countryCode like "PL", "US" etc.

Comment: You can associate country code and phone code in a database for example and use the right one

Comment: I though about it. Is there any mapping countryCode -> phoneCode already supported by Android platform ? If not do you know any lib ?